# Accessing secure site in Android emulator

Tags: android, https, android-emulator

I am trying to get access some Https Sites. Here I am getting Error "Data Connectivity Problem; Secure Connection Could not be established".

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove any configured APN proxy in your networking settings like described here:

[Proxy and SSL connections in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804485/proxy-and-ssl-connections-in-android-emulator)

(`Settings > More > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names > PROVIDER`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you use to establish the connection, nor what level of knowledge in such kind of communication is. So I am just making my guess: using ordinary HttpClient for SSL connection will fail - you will need to trust the server certificate. There are nice ways to make that, but I suggest you start by trusting all certificate using a custom HttpClient as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https). Afterwords you can read on how to create bouncy castle keystores and start trusting the specific certificate.

Please if I got you completely wrong, I will still like to try to help - I will just need some more information. how do you try to access those sites. ca we see some code?

Comment: Its pretty simple scenario.. I'm not trying any secure connection from app.. Just im trying to hit secure site from browser  for exp "https://www.google.com". Even this will fail.

Comment: Hmm it might turn to be the case that it is easier to get secure connection from within an app rather than the browser. The reason being that the browser also needs some trust store and I am not quite sure whether the emulator browsers support that.